# How to generate iCal file from iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented calander applicaion in which I want to send event data through email to another emailid.In that I want to attach one file (iCal file format).So when user get that file and he click on that file then automatically event added in the ical.

Please help me for this query.

Thanks in advance